# How to create correct relationships in laravel for attributes?

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relationship

About my app models

---

**Product**

Each product has one category and multiple attributes

**Category**

Each category has many products and attibutes

**Attribute**

This model contain only unique attributes name.
Each attribute has different value by category (e.g "size" attribute in "T-shirts" category has values like "X", "S", "XL" and in "boots" category has "39", "41", "42" values). I can't create right solution to create relationships in this case for correctly get/search products by attribute or save/sync attributes to products using relationships.

Here is my solution of database structure which doesn't help

[image]

**How to correctly realise attributes in my case?**

Comment: your DB schema seems a bit messy and not in normal form, maybe work on that can make your PHP solution much easier

Comment: That is why I ask for advice. I also didn’t really like my decision, but this is what I could up to this point. I need the right way for the optimal solution to the problem. @Greedo

Comment: Sorry, i didn't formulate clearly. My question is, can you change the DB schema or it's too late for this?

Comment: why do you want generic attributes in the tables? that seem so overkill

Comment: Of course it is possible to change the database schema. Which scheme would you recommend? @Greedo

Comment: Do you recommend a separate table for each? @mrhn

Comment: you did not answer the question, "why" do you need them?

Comment: Generic attributes in tables are used to reduce the list of tables and then in my case attributes are available in two models such as products and categories @mrhn

Answer (score 0):

**Schema changes**
(in some pseudocode)

```
Product: 
 id
 category_id -> foreign(Categories)->on(id)

Categories:
 id
 
Attributes:
 id

Attribute_values: 
 id

Category_attributes
 category_id    -> foreign(Categories)->on(id)
 attribute_id   -> foreign(Attributes)->on(id)
 
Attributes_attributes_values
 attribute_id   -> foreign(Attributes)->on(id)
 attribute_value_id   -> foreign(Attribute_values)->on(id)

Product_attributes
 Product_id    -> foreign(Categories)->on(id)
 attribute_id   -> foreign(Attributes)->on(id)
 attribute_value_id   -> foreign(Attribute_values)->on(id)
```

From this schema you will be able to derive:

**Models** (still simplified pseudocode)

```
Product: 
 $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
 $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttributes::class)->withPivot(attribute_value_id);
```

And with these two relations you will be able to filter both attributes types and values